# Как скомпилировать C# class используя COM type library в PowerShell

Tags: .net, com, powershell

Хочу скомпилировать  C# class, который использует COM type library в PowerShell. Если использует .NET assambly, то использую код

```
Add-Type   -ReferencedAssemblies @( $assemby) -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp
```

Где `$assemby` переменная с .NET assambly.
Когда создаёшь проект в чистом C# , можно добавлять Reference к COM type library. А в powershell можно?
(Про работу с COM в самом Powershell я знаю.)

Comment: Вам надо проделать работу, которую делает `msbuild` при сборке проекта, а именно: импортировать COM type library при помощи утилы `tlbimp` и добавить получившуюся сборку к параметру `ReferencedAssemblies`.

Answer (score 0):

Пример использования одного из методов из библиотеки user32.dll:

```
$signature = @" 
[DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);
"@ 
$SendMouseClick = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name 'SomeName' -PassThru 
$SendMouseClick::mouse_event()
```